# Creating anti-aliased circular mask efficiently

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I am trying to create anti-aliased (weighted and not boolean) circular masks for making circular kernels for use in convolution.

```
radius = 3  # no. of pixels to be 1 on either side of the center pixel
            # shall be decimal as well; not the real radius
kernel_size = 9                
kernel_radius = (kernel_size - 1) // 2
x, y = np.ogrid[-kernel_radius:kernel_radius+1, -kernel_radius:kernel_radius+1]
dist = ((x**2+y**2)**0.5)
mask = (dist-radius).clip(0,1)
print(mask)
```

and the output is

```
array([[1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.  , 0.61, 0.16, 0.  , 0.16, 0.61, 1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.61, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.61, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.16, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.16, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.16, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.16, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 0.61, 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.61, 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.  , 0.61, 0.16, 0.  , 0.16, 0.61, 1.  , 1.  ],
       [1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  ]])
```

Then we can do

```
mask = 1 - mask
print(mask)
```

to get

```
array([[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.39, 0.84, 1.  , 0.84, 0.39, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.39, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 0.39, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.84, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 0.84, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.84, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 0.84, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.39, 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 1.  , 0.39, 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.39, 0.84, 1.  , 0.84, 0.39, 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]])
```

I can now normalize and use this as my circular filter (kernel) in convolution operations.

Note: Radius can be decimal. Eg: `get_circular_kernel(0.5,(5,5))` should give

```
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.08578644, 0.5       , 0.08578644, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.5       , 1.        , 0.5       , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.08578644, 0.5       , 0.08578644, 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]])
```

**I want to generate a million of these** at the very least, with the `kernel_size` fixed and `radius` changing, so is there a better or more efficient way to do this? (maybe without costly operations like sqrt and still stay accurate enough to arc integrals i.e., area covered by the curve in the particular pixel?)

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you mean by "better"? In other words, in what ways does your current solution not meet your needs?

Comment: Also, are these values from this method accurate enough? how do I cross-check if these values are accurate (as in, the value `0.39` should mean that 39% of the pixel area was covered by the curve on that pixel)?

Comment: Again, "accurate enough" is vague (enough for what?) However, it's pretty clear that the diameter of your circle at the horizontal and vertical axes is 7 (just count the ones). If the code were accurate, the diameter would be twice the radius, i.e. 6, and not 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485800/algorithm-for-drawing-an-anti-aliased-circle

Comment: @NPE made changes

Comment: I suspect that your way is actually pretty good and efficient.  You could try to use some [jit-compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49011917/997253) like `numba` which might speed it up.

Comment: Will all the kernels among the million have size 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to generate a large number of kernels *with the same size*, you can greatly improve performance by constructing every kernel in one step rather than one after the other in a loop. You can create a single array of shape `(num_radii, kernel_size, kernel_size)` given `num_radii` values for each kernel. The price of this vectorization is memory: you'll have to fit all these values in RAM, otherwise you should chunk up your millions of radii into a handful of smaller batches and generate each batch again separately.

The only thing you need to change is to take an array of radii (rather than a scalar radius), and inject two trailing singleton dimensions so that your mask creation triggers [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
import numpy as np 

kernel_size = 9
kernel_radius = (kernel_size - 1) // 2
x, y = np.ogrid[-kernel_radius:kernel_radius+1, -kernel_radius:kernel_radius+1]
dist = (x**2 + y**2)**0.5 # shape (kernel_size, kernel_size)

# let's create three kernels for the sake of example
radii = np.array([3, 3.5, 4])[...,None,None] # shape (num_radii, 1, 1)
# using ... allows compatibility with arbitrarily-shaped radius arrays

masks = 1 - (dist - radii).clip(0,1) # shape (num_radii, kernel_size, kernel_size)
```

Now `masks[0,...]` (or `masks[0]` for short, but I prefer the explicit version)  contains the example mask in your question, and `masks[1,...]` and `masks[2,...]` contain the kernels for radii `3.5` and `4`, respectively.

Comment: it should be `[..., None, None]` so it works for 2D numpy arrays as well. If it is `(2,2)` then `[:, None, None]` would give `(2,1,1,2)`, but we want `(2,2,1,1)`

Comment: `for` loop was swallowing so much time, but this **one shot** thingy is incomparably faster...

Comment: For one million `(9,9)` kernels with `for` loop `16.4s` with one shot `0.6s`. Also, I combined the in-place operations as suggested by [J. Martinot-Lagarde](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51011793/3125070) and that further sped up from `0.6s` to `0.5s`

Comment: Yes, if you want all the masks at once this solution is better.

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran indeed, thanks, I updated with the ellipsis. I had a simple 1d array `radii` in mind, but of course it can't hurt to be more general; actually the updated version allows arrays of any shape for `radii`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build millions of masks, you should precompute once what never changes, and compute only the strict necessary for each radius.

You can try something like this:

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, kernel_size):
        self._kernel_size = kernel_size
        self._kernel_radius = (self._kernel_size - 1) // 2

        x, y = np.ogrid[
            -self._kernel_radius:self._kernel_radius+1,
            -self._kernel_radius:self._kernel_radius+1]
        self._dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

    def __call__(self, radius):
        mask = self._dist - radius
        mask = np.clip(mask, 0, 1, out=mask)
        mask *= -1
        mask += 1
        return mask


circle = Circle(kernel_size=9)
for radius in range(1, 4, 0.2):
    mask = circle(radius)  
    print(mask)
```

I did the operations inplace as much as possible to optimize for speed and memory, but for small arrays it won't matter much.

Comment: oh, sorry but radius shall be used as the main param here and it could be in decimals, hence not restricted to only 5 different masks, updated the question and the answer :)

Comment: I understand better now, thanks for the update. The integer division for the radius was misleading ;) The stop value for range is wrong now, I'll update it.