# Render a Circle or Ellipse with Anti-Aliasing

Tags: python, numpy, antialiasing

Assume I have a square raster of given size, and I want to "draw" (render) a circle (or ellipse) of given radius (or major / minor axes) and center.

One way of doing this in Python with NumPy is:

```
import numpy as np


def ellipse(box_size, semisizes, position=0.5, n_dim=2):
    shape = (box_size,) * n_dim
    if isinstance(semisizes, (int, float)):
        semisizes = (semisizes,) * n_dim
    position = ((box_size - 1) * position,) * n_dim
    grid = [slice(-x0, dim - x0) for x0, dim in zip(position, shape)]
    position = np.ogrid[grid]
    arr = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
    for x_i, semisize in zip(position, semisizes):
        arr += (np.abs(x_i / semisize) ** 2)
    return arr <= 1.0

print(ellipse(5, 2).astype(float))
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

which produces a rasterization without [anti-aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_anti-aliasing).
In particular, the pixels that are only *partially* included in the circle get a value of `0` (similarly to pixels excluded from the circle), while pixels entirely included in the circle gets a value of `1`.

With anti-aliasing, the pixels *partially* included in the circle would get a value between `0` and `1` depending on how much of their area is included in the circle.

---

How could I modify the code from above to (possibly cheaply) include anti-aliasing?
I am struggling to see how (if?) I could use the values of `arr`.

Super-sampling-based methods are out of question here.

Eventually, the result should look something like:

```
# [[0.0 0.2 1.0 0.2 0.0]
#  [0.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.2]
#  [1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0]
#  [0.2 1.0 1.0 1.0 0.2]
#  [0.0 0.2 1.0 0.2 0.0]]
```

(where `0.2` should be a value between `0.0` and `1.0` representing how much area of that specific pixel is covered by the circle).

---

## EDIT

I see now obvious way on how to adapt the code from [Creating anti-aliased circular mask efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002815/creating-anti-aliased-circular-mask-efficiently) although obviously, `np.clip()` must be part of the solution.

Comment: Isn't just that `return arr <= 1.0` that makes it binary?

Comment: @usr2564301 yes, but the value of `arr` gives some indication of the distance of the center of a pixel from the ideal circle center. Not how much pixel is inside the ideal circle line. If you'd just return `arr`, you would get distances (squared). and not something that is 1.0 inside, 0.0 outside, and somewhere in between for border pixels, which is how anti-aliasing would work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating anti-aliased circular mask efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002815/creating-anti-aliased-circular-mask-efficiently)

Comment: Are you looking for a mathematical correct answer? Quartering the pixel gives you an accuracy of 0.25; dividing by 10 will be in the 0.01s. Super-sampling is easy and as accurate as you want to have it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fast but not necessarily mathematically correct way of doing this (loosely based on the code from [Creating anti-aliased circular mask efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51002815/creating-anti-aliased-circular-mask-efficiently)) is:

```
import numpy as np


def prod(items, start=1):
    for item in items:
        start *= item
    return start


def ellipse(box_size, semisizes, position=0.5, n_dim=2, smoothing=1.0):
    shape = (box_size,) * n_dim
    if isinstance(semisizes, (int, float)):
        semisizes = (semisizes,) * n_dim
    position = ((box_size - 1) * position,) * n_dim
    grid = [slice(-x0, dim - x0) for x0, dim in zip(position, shape)]
    position = np.ogrid[grid]
    arr = np.zeros(shape, dtype=float)
    for x_i, semisize in zip(position, semisizes):
        arr += (np.abs(x_i / semisize) ** 2)
    if smoothing:
        k = prod(semisizes) ** (0.5 / n_dim / smoothing)
        return 1.0 - np.clip(arr - 1.0, 0.0, 1.0 / k) * k
    elif isinstance(smoothing, float):
        return (arr <= 1.0).astype(float)
    else:
        return arr <= 1.0


n = 1
print(np.round(ellipse(5 * n, 2 * n, smoothing=0.0), 2))
# [[0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
#  [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

n = 1
print(np.round(ellipse(5 * n, 2 * n, smoothing=1.0), 2))
# [[0.   0.65 1.   0.65 0.  ]
#  [0.65 1.   1.   1.   0.65]
#  [1.   1.   1.   1.   1.  ]
#  [0.65 1.   1.   1.   0.65]
#  [0.   0.65 1.   0.65 0.  ]]
```

---

A slightly more general version of this approach has been included in the [`raster_geometry`](https://pypi.org/project/raster-geometry/) Python package (**Disclaimer**: I am the main author of it).